# java: package org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions does not exist

Tags: java, exception, import, package, classpath

I have an import in my codes:
import org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException;

then when I build it from Buidl -> recompile 'file.java', I always got the error:

java: package org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions does not exist.

I am using maven to build it. it's ok. I got lost...

I know if I find the package org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions and put into classpath should solve it. but I don't know where to find the valid pakcage?

Comment: BTW, The tool I used is IntelliJ

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.